# No podspec found for ... in <file>.podspec.json

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have been following [this guide](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/13/creating-a-cocoapod.html) to get a project on mine on CocoaPods. I am currently on the *Testing* section and am getting the error:

```
[!] No podspec found for `AppUpdateTracker` in /Users/aaron/Downloads/AUTCocoaPodsTest/AUTPodTest/Pods/AppUpdateTracker/AppUpdateTracker.podspec.json
```

Linting againt my repo works fine:

```
pod spec lint App-Update-Tracker.podspec

 -> App-Update-Tracker (1.0.0)

Analyzed 1 podspec.

App-Update-Tracker.podspec passed validation.
```

And this is my Podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "App-Update-Tracker"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "AppUpdateTracker is a simple, lightweight iOS library intended to determine basic app install/update behavior."

  s.description  =  <<-DESC
                   This library allows you to easily determine when the user uses your app after a fresh install, when the user updates your app (and the version from which (s)he updated, and how many times the user has opened a given version of your app. This library was created in order to help determine update information so that appropriate data migration logic could be run after an app update.
                   DESC

  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/Stunner/App-Update-Tracker"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE.txt" }
  s.author             = { "Stunner" => "" }
  s.social_media_url   = "http://twitter.com/ajubbal"
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/Stunner/App-Update-Tracker.git", :tag => "1.0.0" }

  s.source_files  = "AppUpdateTracker"
  s.requires_arc = true

end
```

Any idea on how to get around this issue?

Comment: How does your Podfile look? Is it referencing your local Podspec correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your Pod names doesn't match:
The name of the pod is App-Update-Tracker but it's references as AppUpdateTracker.

Comment: Turns out I was using `AppUpdateTracker` in my Podfile when I needed to be using `App-Update-Tracker`.

Comment: I am getting the same issue and my pod name is correct , still getting this issue, any idea why this is happening? My pod spec file is in different folder and my test project is in different folder. Does this cause a issue?

Comment: I think I have the same issue as you @PoojaShah did you find the reason?

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik no, if you find then let me know.

Comment: Are you using your private podspecs @PoojaShah?